# Using requests to POST to pastebin API

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I simply cannot get this to work.

```
header = {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf8"}
params = {"api_dev_key": dev_key, "api_user_name": username, "api_user_password": password}
req = requests.post("http://pastebin.com/api/api_login.php", params = json.dumps(params), headers = header)
print(req.status_code, req.reason, req.text)
```

The variables (my credentials) are just strings.
The response I get:

> (200, 'OK', u'Bad API request, invalid api_dev_key')

There's nothing wrong with the key, this POST works fine when I use https://www.hurl.it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to just use *data=params*:

```
req = requests.post("http://pastebin.com/api/api_login.php", data=params)
```

Comment: sometimes adding invalid headers also gives the "invalid api_dev_key" error